# Scraping website's Blob URLs

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

Is there a way to grab the data being held in a video tag when the src is set to a Blob URL on a website.  I've tried adding a link to the page in developer tools with code such as:

```
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = {BLOB URL};
a.download = fileName;
a.click();
```

However this leads to an empty download as if the blob is not there anymore. It's possible that the website has already revoked the url, but is there any other way to grab the data then?  Or if the blob references a media source is it possible to convert the blob back to the media source object?

Comment: Well once you construct a blob url of a fully loaded video it doesn't matter whether that website revoked the url or crashed or got shutdown , the video stays as is as long as the browser is open and opening the blob url will open the video just as it would normally coz it's now a browser content and not some external website content. I cannot say anything about your issue unless you post all the relevant code

Comment: Hmm ok interesting, do you know how you would access that data then? I basically opened a Youtube page and copied the blob url from the video tag into that code block above and ran it in the console tab of developer tools, however that didn't seem to work.